# iOS - Video resolution on retina display?

Tags: ios, video, retina-display

I am embedding local, short videos inside my app. The size of the video (width and height) are predefined to fit the view they will be played in.

**Edited**
Let say I have a video 800 height & 650 width.

I want to display it in the iPhone on a 400 * 325 view, so i resize it to this size. 
Should I make an other version of 800 * 640 for the retina iPhone?

What are the rules for video resolution on retina display deices? will I benefit a better video on retina if I will double the resolution?

Thanks

Shani

Comment: The resolution is only related to your video source file. If the resolution of video is less than retina resolution (480 x 960) and when it fits the frame of your player, the content will be stretched.

Comment: You do not need to resize it to 400 x 325, just use its original resolution and it will resize according to the frame of player.

Comment: Thanks again, so you say I should ship only the large version and set the frame.