# What about movies on retina @2x?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

We know how things work with images on retina with @2x and without it. But what about movies?

Do I have to have a movie double the resolution of the other for retina displays? The naming convention @2x stands for movies? What about having just the bigger one and make it fit full screen?

Comment: Take a look at: [iOS - Video resolution on retina display?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893076/ios-video-resolution-on-retina-display)

Comment: so the answer is: I should work just with the big movie, right? In fact this app of mine will be exclusively iOS 7 for iPad. I wonder if any non-retina devices beyond iPad 1 will be able to run iOS 7.

Comment: iPad mini and iPad 2 will be able to run iOS 7.

Comment: I forgot the mini. Thanks. Post your comment as an answer, so I can give you the points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it comes to videos, there is generally no reason to include two files. Your non-retina device should still be powerful enough to be able to play higher resolution videos (within reason). The videos will just be scaled down to fit the frame of your video player.

Since you are targeting iOS 7, you will still have iPad mini and iPad 2 non-retina devices.

Videos are generally compressed with h.264, and they scale quite well. Even upscaled videos look fine, without much added blockiness. Smaller resolution videos of the same quality are smaller in size. Therefore, when choosing the video resolution, you might choose somewhere between non-retina and retina resolutions, and thereby save on storage space as well.

Comment: Also, since videos are based on JPEG compression, even upscaled video looks good on Retina screens, so the solution might be to include video of resolution between 1x (downscaled) and 2x (upscaled). This can save disk space.